# How to add a reference to a COM library to ASP.Net 5?

Tags: asp.net, com, asp.net-core

I'm trying to migrate an ASP.NET MVC Project to ASP.NET 5 MVC 6, this project references an assembly that reference a COM library, so, I need to add the reference in Project.json to that library, is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a local Nuget package for your library. You can use the [Nuget Package Explorer](https://docs.nuget.org/create/using-a-gui-to-build-packages) to make a package.

Then you'll need to add a reference to your local directory to your Nuget package sources.

Comment: Does Nuget support adding COM libraries?

Comment: I've gotten a PDF creator and an XLS generating library to work, so it should.